# Imageresizer cache azure storage quota limits

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm using ImageResizer as an Azure webapp with a service plan with 50 Gb file storage. My settings for DiskCache are:

```
    <diskcache dir="~/imagecache" autoclean="true" hashModifiedDate="true" subfolders="1024" asyncWrites="true" asyncBufferSize="10485760" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" logging="true"/>
```

But that doesn't seem to stop the imagecache folder to get to the 50 Gb limit quite quickly. I have around 100 Gb of images in blob storage (original size), not all will be used on the same day, however the same image could be cached with different parameters multiple times. The images cached are around 200Kb average?.

Is there a way to stop the storage filling up so quick? Is there maybe a better way of using DiskCache? or use something else? The Premium Plans with 250Gb and decent CPU/RAM are far too expensive to justify the cost for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit the cache by files size, only by a (very) rough count. Deleting the cache and setting subfolders="256" should keep you under 50GB, assuming that 200kb average holds true.

... However, if your cache fills up "quickly" (as in 1-3 days), then you're probably going to experience serious cache churn and poor performance as your disk write queue skyrockets.

You might consider using a CDN if you can't get storage space for, say, 10 days worth of cached files.

Comment: Looked at CDN but Azure doesn't support SSL bindings just yet

Comment: I would suggest anything other than Azure CDN.

Comment: Thanks Nathanael for this. Azure has now added support for custom domain SSL bindings in their CDN. Is it as simple as pointing my images domain to the cdn rather than storage? how is the images processing going to work if users request different image sizes/settings?

Comment: You point the CDN to the imageresizer server, not the bucket.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's working now, still fills up storage quite quickly though.